# Accelerometer camera movement perpendicular to floor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
float myXaccel, myYaccel;

Vector3 acceler = Input.acceleration;

        myXaccel = Mathf.Lerp(myXaccel, acceler.y, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        myYaccel = Mathf.Lerp(myYaccel, -acceler.x, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        Quaternion rot = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
        rot.x = myXaccel; 
        rot.y = myYaccel;
        Camera.main.transform.rotation = rot;
```

It works very well and the camera follows the accelerometer up/down/left/right.

If the phone is facing the ground.

But I'd need to do the same while the phone is perpendicular to floor.
I must see my game plan as here i'm looking it parallel to the floor.

If I rotate the cam with a quaternion (90, 0, 0), I can see the rotated view but the accelerometer sensor isn't longer working at that point.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: you might need to calibrate the origin each time you start with game scene. I think it is also given in the unity3d.com 's learn section under space shooter

Comment: I followed the space shooter sample but isn't working. What i need is simply to rotate the plan of 90 degrees on X axis, so the default plan is not pointed to horizontal phone but to vertical phone.
So far i earned the best result translating the camera with:

transform.up = -(Input.acceleration.normalized);

But in someway this mess the accelerometer input, since from vertical position i can't no longer read from y axis correctly.